# P(x $\geq$ c) = P(x = c) + P(x > c) Always True?

Tags: probability

I apologize. This is a dumb question.

If x is a random variable (discrete or continuous) , is the following always true?

P(x $\geq$  c) = P(x = c) + P(x > c)

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The events $\{\omega \in \Omega\ |\ X = c\}$ and $\{\omega \in \Omega\ |\ X > c\}$ are disjoint, so yes.

Comment: Thank you so much.

Comment: Let me also point out that if $X$ is continuous and has a density $f_X(x)$, then $P(X = c) = 0$ and $P(X \ge c) = P(X > c)$ -- do not be confused into thinking that $P(X = c) = f_X(c)$.

Comment: It's worth noting that we can have $P(X = c) \neq 0$ when $X$ is a real valued random variable. Nevertheless, the identity in the OP is true for the reason that RJTK gives.